# what is difference between ge ttags and send tags in onesignal push notification give a example

Tags: push-notification, onesignal

i'm try to use one signal push notification in an app. i need to send specific notification to specific category of users. how to do that how to add that tag to one signal through android. Anyone please explain me with example

Answer (score 1):

You can call [sendTags](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-sdk-api#sendTags) or the [sendTag](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-sdk-api#section-sendtag) method on the OneSignal Android SDK to add tags to the user.

```
OneSignal.sendTag("key", "value");
```